# Creating rule to 'Send As'

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I am trying to create a rule in outlook that looks at outgoing emails (the 'apply rule on message I send' rule)

when Subject contains 'test':
send as 'address2@email.com' (an address the user has 'Send As' permissions for

I have managed to set up a rule to identify the subject contents, but I am stuck for creating a 'Send as' rule.

Comment: What version of outlook?

Comment: @Raystafarian - 2007